# Deleting millions of log files with Powershell

Tags: powershell

On an old server we have millions of log files. These log files are part of an integration framework we are running that has never been cleaned up. There are approximately 1.8 million XML log files spread out over 3000 directories.

The folders have the following structure:

`D:\Program Files\<Our company name>\<Integration framework version [5 folders]>\Environment\<Customer Name [20 folders]>\<Integration name [Between 1-15 folders]>\<Release version [1-10 folders]>\XmlLogs\<Date [Hundreds of folders]>\logname.xml`

Examples:

`D:\Program Files\Company\Company Integration 4.5.5\Environment\Company A\GenericEmailer\Release1.0.0.I1\XmlLogs\01-01-2014\logname.xml`

`D:\Program Files\Company\Company Integration 4.5.6\Environment\Company B\GlobalEmailer\Release1.2.3.I2\XmlLogs\01-01-2019\logname.xml`

My plan was searching for all the XmlLogs directories and emptying those directories, but whenever I do a Get-ChildItem the whole server freezes and never outputs the results.

`Get-ChildItem -Directory "D:\Program Files\Company\Company Integration 4.5.6\Environment\Company A\" -Recurse -Name -Include "XmlLogs"`

What is the right way to do this and also delete all the log files?

Comment: Unless there are other XML files you want to preserve you could try `Get-ChildItem 'D:\...\Company A' -Filter *.xml -Recurse -Force`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry, I forgot to mention that .xml files are also used as configuration files. So I don't think that would work. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Then you need to provide more criteria for identifying the files. Are they always named "logname.xml" or is that just a placeholder name in your question? Are they always stored in a subfolder tree "XmlLogs\##-##-####"?

Comment: It sounds like ```Get-ChildItem``` with the ```-Recurse``` switch is just busy traversing your entire folder structure, and that's possibly impacting disk performance on an "old" server. You could try adding ```-Depth 1``` so it doesn't need to look into all the date subfolders to find your "XmlLogs" folders (or it might be ```-Depth 2``` - try experimenting!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try this (modifiy the like like you want or use -match operator +regex expression)

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files" -directory -recurse | % {

  if ($_.fullname -like '*\XmlLogs\*')
  {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -file -filter "*.xml" | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
  }

}
```

Note 1 : To really remove you must remove "-whatif" option in my example

Note 2 : For better performance you can use 'D:\Program Files\Company' if the company name doesn't change.